# when to use def - groovy shell

Tags: groovy, closures, nextflow

I'm new to nextflow which uses groovy heavily. I'm learning groovy to learn closures so that can be learned and implemented in nextflow. I've a small piece of code, which I'm trying to print and execute in groovy shell.

```
f_name="MM-265-DNA-T-01-01_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz"
matcher = f_name =~ /^(MM-\w+)-DNA-(\w+)-.*_L(\d+).*$/
def (_, sample_id, sample_type, lane) = matcher[0].findAll()
```

When I try to print sample_type that wouldn't print `sample_id` and give me an error `Unknown property: sample_id`
I've tried the following ways to print sample id but fail:

"${sample_id}"
"$sample_id"
${sample_id}
$sample_id

The code works fine if I use `(_, sample_id, sample_type, lane) = matcher[0].findAll()` But why it doesn't work with `def`?
I got this from another post of mine https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/a/21339/862

Comment: in plain groovy script `def` declares local variable of script/function/scope, when without `def` groovy creates variable (property) that is visible through whole script. i'm not familiar with nextflow, but with `def` it really matters where you declare variable and where you are using it - it must be the same scope.

Comment: The code you shared works just fine here, with Nextflow 23.06.0-edge.

Comment: @mribeirodantas Hi, yes it migh work fine in nexflow, however I was trying in a groovyshell. One small question - is there a nextflow `shell`?

Comment: Ok, let's make something clear: Nextflow is a language built on top of Groovy. It's not Groovy, so running Nextflow code in a Groovy shell shouldn't work, by design 

You can try the `nextflow console` (it's a command).

Answer (score 2):

Your Groovy code by itself is fine, but Nextflow will raise an error if that code is moved inside a [`workflow`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/dsl2.html#workflow) block for example. I sometimes see errors like this, which may be the problem here:

```
ERROR ~ Script compilation error
- file : main.nf
- cause: Variable `matcher` already defined in the process scope @ line X, column Y.
```

We could simplify the example to just:

```
workflow {

    foo = 'foooooooo'

    def bar = foo
}
```

Results:

```
ERROR ~ Script compilation error
- file : main.nf
- cause: Variable `foo` already defined in the process scope @ line 5, column 15.
```

I think this has something to do with how Nextflow tracks (internally) the use of global variables<sup>[1](https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/blob/v23.04.2/modules/nextflow/src/main/groovy/nextflow/ast/VariableVisitor.groovy#L99-L120)</sup>. The error is rather unexpected but as to whether or not it is a bug or feature would be a question for the Nextflow developers. It's not clear (to me at least) whether or not variables on the right-hand side of the assignment operator should be added to the set of referenced variables.

In any case, the solution though is to prefer local variables using the `def` keyword:

```
workflow {
    
    def f_name = "MM-265-DNA-T-01-01_L003_R1_001.fastq.gz"
    def matcher = f_name =~ /^(MM-\w+)-DNA-(\w+)-.*_L(\d+).*$/
    
    def (_, sample_id, sample_type, lane) = matcher[0].findAll()

    println(sample_id)
    println(sample_type)
    println(lane)
}
```

Results:

```
MM-265
T
003
```

Comment: Hi @Steve, thanks as always. I was able to to print `_, sample_id, lane, sample_type` however, within the groovy shell `def` didn't and doesn't work whilst capturing output form the regular expression.

Comment: No worries at all @DeathMetal. If there are still issues, please post the full code that does not produce the expected results. The code you have provided will run in a Groovy shell and unpack the matched output as expected. I thought I may have guessed what the issue was, but it looks like I was wrong..